# How to filter a list of words as likely candidates for a secret word, given that I know certain letters

Tags: python, string, algorithm, permutation

So I've been really struggling with this problem. First of all let's lay-out the basic rules that this Python program must follow:

> Lingo is a popular word-guessing game show on television. The number
> of letters of a target word to be guessed is given, and often also the
> first letter. Players then make guesses subject to these restrictions
> (number of letters and possibly also first letter), and the game tells
> them which letters are correct and in the correct place, marked by a
> red square (X), and which letters are correct but not in the correct
> place, marked by a yellow circle (O). We do not use superfluous yellow
> circles, i.e. a letter is marked correct at most as often as it
> appears in the target word. If not all occurrences of the same letter
> can get a yellow circle this way, priority is given from left to right
> (but of course red squares have priority over yellow circles).

First I needed to create a function compare that compares a guessed word with a target word. The two inputs are string of the same length that entirely consist of lowercase ASCII letters. The output is a string of the same length consisting of the symbols **X, O** and -, where **X** represent a red square, **O** represents a yellow circle and **-** represents nothing.

Examples:

**compare("health", "teethe")** must return **"OX--O-"**,

**compare("rhythm", "teethe")** must return **"---XX-"**,

**compare("mutate", "teethe")** must return **"--O-OX"**,

**compare("teethe", "mutate")** must return **"O--O-X"**,

Now I've already successfully solved this part, but the next part is where I am stuck.

A function filter_targets(targets, guess_results) must be implemented.

This function must satisfy the following:

● targets is a list (or any other iterable) of possible target words; all words in targets must be of the same length.

● guess_results is a dictionary. Its keys are guessed words (which need not be in the target list) whose associated values are their compare results with a possible target.

● It must return a list of target words in targets that actually do satisfy all
the comparisons appearing in guess_results .

Examples:

Suppose targets contains all English 6-letter words obtained using the aforementioned word list and load function. Let guess_results contain the results of the first two guesses in the example given:

guess_results = **{"health": "OX--O-", "rhythm": "---XX-"}**

Then based on these results, we can see which words are still possible:

filter_targets(targets, guess_results) will return the following list:

**["depths", "peitho", "seethe", "teethe", "tenths"]**

Now my current program looks like this, it is very dirty code in my opinion and I would really love to see some implementations that are right. This code also still doesn't do what I want it to.

My reasoning was that if I convert the word or words in guess_results (it must also be able to take a single input, as my code hereunder is taking with the mem_list function) to the "**XO-**" format, then store all permutations of this format in a list, I can convert the words in wordlist to the format too. I would then check for every permutation in the list if it matches the "**XO-**" format of any word in the wordlist I am looping through, then store all matches in a separate list. I would then return that list as an answer.

I thought I was getting very close with this logic, but I now can't seem to permutate in a way the leaves some characters in place. And my current implementation would only work for a single word input.

```
from itertools import permutations

def load_words(file):
    result = set()
    with open(file) as f:
      for line in f.readlines():
        word = line.strip().lower()
        if word.isalpha() and word.isascii():
          result.add(word)
    return sorted(result)

english_words = load_words("words.txt")
dutch_words = load_words("wordlist.txt")

english_10 = [word for word in dutch_words if len(word) == 10]

    def filter_targets(targets, guess_results):
        mem_list = ["-" for x in range(len("kasgelden"))]
        perm_list = mem_list  



    # Checking X
    for guess in guess_results.keys():
        for idx in range(len(guess)):
            if guess_results[guess][idx] == 'X':
                mem_list[idx] = guess[idx] 
    
    o_list = []

    # Checking O
    for guess in guess_results.keys():
        for idx in range(len(guess)):
            if guess_results[guess][idx] == 'O':
                mem_var = guess[idx]
                o_list.append(mem_var)

    add_list = mem_list

    o_min = 0
    o_max = len(o_list)
    y = 0
    
    # Adding the "O"
    for element in add_list:
        if element == "-" and o_min < o_max:
            add_list[y] = o_list[o_min]
            o_min += 1
            y += 1
        else:
            y += 1
    
    check_list = list(permutations(add_list))

guess_results = {"kasgelden": "--O--OOX-"}
d6 = [word for word in dutch_words if len(word) == 9] 

filter_targets(d6, guess_results)
```

In this single world example: filter_targets(dw9, **{"kasgelden": "--O--OOX-"})** should return **["doorspoel", "doublures", "hoofdstel", "moordspel",
"schildjes", "slurfdier", "thuisduel", "woordspel"] .** With dw9 being all the words with a length of 9.

This problem is driving me completely crazy and has consumed three days of free time already, I hope someone can nudge me in the right direction here!

English wordlist I am using: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words.txt

Dutch wordlist I am using: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenTaal/opentaal-wordlist/master/wordlist.txt

Comment: For each Dutch word, call your `compare` function with the Dutch word and the word from the `guess_results`. If the string returned from `compare` **doesn't** match the `XO-` string in `guess_results`, then the word is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The guess results tell you two types of things:

- For each position, is the guessed letter required or excluded.
- For each guessed letter, does it appear in the correct answer.

You can track the first thing by maintaining a regex.
You can track the second thing with two strings, one containing needed characters, one containing forbidden ones.

You can build those as follows:

```
regex = ["[^^]"]*wordlen
required = restricted = ''
for guess,result in guess_results:
    needs = never = ''
    for i,score in enumerate(result):
        letter = guess[i] 
        if score == 'X':
            regex[i]=letter
            needs += letter
        elif score == 'O':
            regex[i] = regex[i].replace(']',letter+']')
            needs += letter
        else:
            regex[i] = regex[i].replace(']',letter+']')
            never += letter
        # don't reject a '-' found on doubled letter if one was needed.
        restricted += ''.join(c for c in never if c not in needs)
        # track the correct number of required letters.
        required = ''.join([c*max(required.count(c),needs.count(c)) for c in set(required)] +
                   [c for c in needs if c not in required])
```

Then filtering the wordlist becomes

```
valid = [w for w in wordlist if (
    re.match(''.join(regex), w) and
    all(w.count(c)>=required.count(c) for c in required) and
    not any(c in w for c in restricted) )]
```